# DEP (Data Execution Prevention) Error running PDFCreator

Tags: pdfcreator

Someone complained to me that they get DEP errors in XP when running [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/). I have never had such an issue. I looked on the sourceforge forum for PDFCreator and it seems some people do have this problem. I've yet to see a specific cause, or an example of the developer responding to these complaints. Does anyone know what the cause of the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the basic idea of [DEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention) implies the fundamental cause: PDFCreator is trying to execute code in a memory segment that XP thinks is data.  One reason that this might be happening to others and not to you is that your DEP policy is probably the default `OptIn`, and theirs might be set to a more-restrictive `OptOut` or `AlwaysOn`.

The more specific reason why DEP is being triggered is a matter of some deep debugging in PDFCreator.

Comment: @chaos, I understand what a DEP is. I'm looking for the specific reason that this one is triggered.

Comment: Okay.  If DEP policy level isn't specific enough, then you need to find someone who can replicate the error (or possibly replicate it yourself by changing DEP policy) and run PDFCreator under a debugger and see what code it is that's triggering DEP.  And hope that running it under a debugger doesn't prevent the error from happening.